# Probability number being drawn

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 3 functions : `Id`, `Name`, `Probability`.

```
ID - Name - Probability

1 -  T1   -  1

2 -  T2   -  2

3 -  T3  -   3

4 -  T4   -  1

5 -  T5  -   3
```

Probability 1-20%

```
        2-30%

        3-50%
```

This query draws a lot of 4 employees.

```
FROM 'C:\temp\colaboradores_teste.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW=4,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

/* Sorteio funcionarios do dia */
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID FROM RH_Alcoolemia_FXP WHERE IDInterno is null  and CAST(DataControlo AS DATE) = CAST(getdate() AS DATE) 
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    /* Random do funcionario */
    SELECT TOP 1 @IDInterno = A.IDInterno, @Nome = A.Nome FROM #temporaria A
    WHERE A.IDInterno not IN (select IDInterno FROM RH_Alcoolemia_FXP WHERE cast(DataControlo as DATE) = cast(getdate() as date) AND IDInterno is not null) 
    order by NEWID()

    update RH_Alcoolemia_FXP set IDInterno = @IDInterno, Nome = @Nome WHere ID = @ID

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID
END
```

And the output is this:

```
Id-Id-Name

233-3-T3

234-1-T1

235-5-T5

236-2-T2
```

According to the probability of each official I liked to raffle an official. 
If it is 3 the official is more likely to leave than the official who has the 1.

Comment: Instead of images you should post sample data as insert statements to a table. And then post actual code instead of a picture. Last but not least...you seem to have forgotten to ask a question. What do you expect as output here?

Comment: @SeanLange . . . I mean, if the images made sense.  But those images don't correspond to the question being asked.